# Get count of lDs where all status is greater than equal to 1

Tags: sql-server

I want to select count of ids where all status is greater than equal to 1

I want something like this

```
SELECT count(ID)FROM  table where all status >= 1
```

| ID | status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |

As you can see in the table where ID = 1,3 has all status greater than equal to 1.
I want to select the count of those IDs.
For example, I want count 2 from the above table.
How can I get those ids count where all status is >=1

Edited:Edited table

Comment: A conditional `COUNT` in the `HAVING`?

Comment: Yeah my bad. I made a mistake while typing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the `ID` where all status are `>=1` you can use

```
SELECT ID
FROM   Table1
GROUP  BY ID
HAVING MIN([status]) >= 1
```

to count them you can use

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   (SELECT ID
        FROM   Table1
        GROUP  BY ID
        HAVING MIN([status]) >= 1) T
```